# Imbalance Learn "balanced_batch_generator" for > 2 dimensional data

Tags: keras, imblearn

I am using imbalanced learn's "balanced_batch_generator" to try to perform undersampling on image array which has 4 dimensions. I ran the code below:

```
training_generator, steps_per_epoch = balanced_batch_generator(x_train, y_train, sampler=NearMiss(), batch_size=10)
```

and got the following error:

```
ValueError: Found array with dim 4. Estimator expected <= 2.
```

I am aware that this function does not accept > 2 dimensional data however I am wondering if there is an work around to this. I would perform under/over sampling myself by just manually splitting the data, however i want to make use of keras's nicely implemented functions such as `NearMiss` to intelligently sample my data.

Answer (score 1):

You need to reshape the array for your `x_train`:

```
x.train.shape #So you know the values for all 4 dims (1st dim, 2nd dim, 3rd dm, 4th dm)
x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0],-1)
```

Then use the `balanced_batch_generator`. Afterwards:

```
x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0], initial Value for the 2nd dim, initial Value for the 3rd, initial Value for the 4th)

for x_train, y_train in training_generator:
    break
```

And your `x_train` contains balanced batches with its initial dimensions. You don't need to reshape `y_train` because it only consists of the labels. (`dim <=2`)

If you do not want to type in the values of the dims all the time, I would use variables that save the values.